# Write during paging through a Query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's assume I query for items with a specific hash key, and while I'm iterating through the query results' pages, a new item with such a hash key is put into the table. Is it possible it will be present in the next pages I request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

If the new item falls in the range in a position after the last page you retrieved, it may get included in the next results. If your query uses consistent reads then you will get it. Without consistent reads you *may* get it but it's not guaranteed due to eventual consistency.

Of course, if the item falls in the range before the page you've last retrieved then you would have to restart the query from the top since items are returned in order of the range key values.

This is fairly easy to test by creating a table with a string partition key and a numeric range key. In a for loop add several 10s of thousand items with the sam arbitrary partition key value. Then start a query and get the first page. After the first page is returned, insert an item with a range key value that would fall on the next page and make the query for the second page (with consistent reads to make sure you get the item) and then look for the new item in the results.